# Generate a String that matches a RegEx in Python

Tags: python, regex, stringbuilder

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reversing a regular expression in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492716/reversing-a-regular-expression-in-python)

I think I ran into a problem that sounds easier than it is... I'm not too sure. I want to define a regular expression, and I want to build a number of strings matching it.

Is there any module I can import that has got this functionality? Preferably not a brute-force approach using `re.search` or `re.match`. There must be a more elegant way to do that.

Comment: look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492716/reversing-a-regular-expression-in-python

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I've been working on a little helper library for [generating random strings with Python](https://github.com/leapfrogonline/rstr)

It includes a method, `xeger()` that allows you to create a string from a regex:

```
>>> import rstr
>>> rstr.xeger(r'[A-Z]\d[A-Z] \d[A-Z]\d')
u'M5R 2W4'
```

Right now, it works with most basic regular expressions.

Comment: No Python3 version?

Comment: Works in python3.8.1

Answer (score 13):

The exrex module does this: https://github.com/asciimoo/exrex.

Comment: +1 Works like a charm! It even install with `easy_install` :)

Comment: Alas, it's GPL; you can't use it in commercial software without contaminating it.

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/leapfrogdevelopment/rstr/ has a `xeger` method and is MIT

Comment: To clarify JDonner's comment for anyone finding this: it's AGPL; you can't even use it in server-side commercial software without releasing the source code to the entire executable that uses this library.

Comment: @JDonner, btown - you're saying that like it's a bad thing.

Comment: I guess it's not necessarily a bad thing, but it's very important that people understand the requirements of the license before using the library!

Answer (score 0):

For some regular expressions, the list of possible strings can be infinite. For example:

```
a*
```

includes

```
a
aa
aaa
```

etc. Thus, there is no way to generate all strings for a given regex.

Comment: More to the point, any function you write to generate an arbitrary string could get stuck in an infinite loop at a*

Comment: asciimoo points to `exrex` which is implemented using generators. That way you can easily control the output and the size of it.

Comment: Not really. The requirement is to match a regex. "a" works, no need to generate all the possible scenarios.