# Python generate string based on regex format

Tags: python, regex

I have some difficulties learning `regex` in python. I want to parse my tornado web route configuration along with arguments into a request path string without handlers request.path method.
For example, I have route with patterns like:

`/entities/([0-9]+)`

`/product/([0-9]+/actions`

The expected result combine with integer parameter (123) will be a string like:

`/entities/123`

`/product/123/actions`

How do I generate string based on that pattern?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Could you edit your question to include some more example inputs and their expected outputs? Also, while you're at it, explain why you need to generate these strings?

Comment: Generating string from regexp is not something available in the library of any language I am familiar with. However, if you search, there are some projects that do it. Basically, you need to generate the transition graph based on the regexp, then randomly walk it. Some modern "regexps" are not actually regular expressions, and it would be harder to make generators for them (e.g. any zero-width assertion complicates matters a lot).

Comment: Thanks for your answer Amadan. Do you have any lib example that could save my problems written in python?

Comment: A great way to play with python regex is with the [oneline web tool](http://pythex.org/)

Answer (score 1):

This might be a possible duplicate to:
[Reversing a regular expression in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492716/reversing-a-regular-expression-in-python)
[Generate a String that matches a RegEx in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4627464/generate-a-string-that-matches-a-regex-in-python)

---

Using the answer provided by @bjmc a solution works like this:

```
>>> import rstr
>>> intermediate = rstr.xeger(\d+)
>>> path = '/product/' + intermediate + '/actions'
```

Depending on how long you want your intermediate integer, you could replace the regex: `\d{1,3}`

Comment: Thank you for your code example, but I assume it will generate a random one, isnt it?