# How can I generate two random chars with .join?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make my program print a serial with a base and two randoms

```
import random
import string

charList = "A", "B", "C", "D", "C", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M",
"O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"
"6", "7", "8", "9"
y27Base = ["U0330V", "U0330W", "U0330X", "U0330Y"]

whatSerial = input("What serial?").upper()

def y27(y27Base, charList):
    return y27Base + "".join([random.choice(charList) for x in range(2)]) + " -> Y27"
if whatSerial == "Y27F":
    for i in y27Base:
        for i2 in charList:
            print(y27(i, i2))
```

what I want is for the program to print y27Base with 2 randoms so for e.x

U0330V9D
U0330XZ7

and I'd want it to print as many as possible

Thanks alot in advance

Comment: Can you elaborate on what problem you are facing?

Comment: "As many as possible" doesn't sound like random choice any more. It's rather a brute force algorithm

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate a String that matches a RegEx in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4627464/generate-a-string-that-matches-a-regex-in-python)

Comment: @GalAbra: a) OP has no Regex, b) the accepted solution does not generate "as many as possible"

Comment: @ThomasWeller Now I understand why this is being downvoted. Brute force indeed. I've retracted the flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your critical problem is that you pass single characters to the function:

```
    for i2 in charList:
        print(y27(i, i2))
```

Thus, your function has only *one* character from which to choose, and you get the double letters that plague your output.

To fix this, simply pass in the character list from your main program:

```
for i in y27Base:
    print(y27(i, charList))
```

Output:

```
U0330VFG -> Y27
U0330WDC -> Y27
U0330XEM -> Y27
U0330YCI -> Y27
```

There is no limit to "as many times as possible": you can loop on this inner statement as much as you like.