# Regular Expressions python3

Tags: python, regex

I try to learn python3 and i am stack little bit with the regular expressions. I study the HOWTO for this but i did not understand very well.this page

```
    1\d2\D2
    ^a\w+z$
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking.  Do you want example strings that match these regular expressions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reversing a regular expression in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492716/reversing-a-regular-expression-in-python)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can generate example strings by reading the expression and choosing appropriate characters step by step.

for example, 1\d2\D2:

```
1\d2\D2 -> 1
^ 1 means a literal number 1

1\d2\D2 -> 17
 ^^ \d means any digit (0-9).  let's choose 7.

1\d2\D2 -> 172
   ^ 2 means a literal number 2.

1\d2\D2 -> 172X
    ^^ \D means anything *but* a digit (0-9).  let's choose X

1\d2\D2 -> 172X2
      ^ 2 means a literal number 2.
```

so `172X2` would be matched by `1\d2\D2`

your next one - `^a\w+z$` - can have multiple lengths:

```
^a\w+z$
^ this means we need to be at the start of a line (and we are, so that's cool)

^a\w+z$ -> a
 ^ a means a literal letter a

^a\w+z$ -> a4
  ^^ \w means a digit, letter, or "_".  let's choose 4.

^a\w+z$ -> a4
    ^ + means we can return to whatever is to the left, if we want, so let's do that...

^a\w+z$ -> a4Q
  ^^ \w means a digit, letter, or "_".  let's choose Q.

^a\w+z$ -> a4Q
    ^ + means we can return to whatever is to the left, if we want, so let's do that...

^a\w+z$ -> a4Q1
  ^^ \w means a digit, letter, or "_".  let's choose 1.

^a\w+z$ -> a4Q1
    ^ + means we can return to whatever is to the left, but now let's stop

^a\w+z$ -> a4Q1z
     ^ z means a literal letter z

^a\w+z$ -> a4Q1z
      ^ $ means we must be at the end of the line, and we are (and so cannot add more)
```

so `a4Q1z` would be matched by `^a\w+z$`.  so would `a4z` (you can check...)

note that `*` is like `+` in that you can jump back and repeat but *also* it means that you can completely skip what is to the left (in other words, `+` means "repeat at least once", but `*` means "repeat zero or more" (the "zero" being the skip)).

*update*:

`[abc]` means pick any one of `a`, `b` or `c`.

`x{2,3}` means add `x` 2 to 3 times (like `+` but with limits to the number of times).  so, `xx` or `xxx`.

`\1` is a bit more complicated.  you need to find what would have been inside the first (because the number 1) set of parentheses and add that.  so, for example, `(\d+)\1` would match `2323` if you had worked from left to right and chosen `23` for `(\d+)`.

Comment: @ksofos - i've added another example.

Comment: you can thank me by marking the answer as correct, if you think it is (click the tick mark)!

Comment: Ok. So if i understand well for the 3rd example i ll have

   ^1(2|34)5(6|78)9$

   12569

or

   134569

or

   125789

:-)

Answer (score 0):

To generate some samples that would be matched, one would probably parse the regex and send each chunk of the regex to a function you would write like `getRandomSatisfyingText`.  Call it a bunch of times until you get 3 unique strings.  It probably wouldn't be too hard until you started supporting atomic assertions (lookaheads and behinds).