# Randomly generate a string that does NOT match a given regular expression

Tags: python, regex

For testing purposes on a project I'm working on, I have a need to, if given a regular expression, randomly generate a string that will **FAIL** to be matched by it.  For instance, if I'm given this regex:

```
^[abcd]d+
```

Then I should be able to generate strings such as:

```
hnbbad
uduebbaef
9f8;djfew
skjcc98332f
```

...each of which does NOT match the regex, but NOT generate:

```
addr32
bdfd09usdj
cdddddd-9fdssee
```

...each of which DO.  In other words, I want something like an anti-Xeger.

Does such a library exist, preferably in Python (if I can understand the theory, I can most likely convert it to Python if need be)?  I gave some thought to how I could write this, but given the scope of regular expressions, it seemed that might be a much harder problem than what things like Xeger can tackle.  I also looked around for a pre-made library to do this, but either I'm not using the right keywords to search or nobody's had this problem before.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reversing a regular expression in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492716/reversing-a-regular-expression-in-python)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My initial instinct is, no, such a library does not exist because it's not possible. You can't be sure that you can find a valid input for any arbitrary regular expression in a reasonable amount of time.

For example, proving whether a number is prime is believed to be a hard to solve mathematical problem. The following regular expression matches any string which is at least 10000 characters long and whose total length is a prime number:

```
(?!(..+)\1+$).{10000}
```

I doubt that any library exists that can find a valid input to this regular expression in reasonable time. And this is a very easy example with a simple solution, e.g. `'x' * 10007` will work. It would be possible to come up with other regular expressions that are much harder to find valid inputs for.

I think the only way you are going to solve this is if you limit yourself to some subset of all possible regular expressions.

---

But having said that *if* you have a magical library that generates text that matches for *any* arbitrary regular expression then all you need to do is generate a regular expression that matches all the strings that *don't* match your original expression.

Luckily this is possible using a negative lookahead:

```
^(?![\s\S]*(?:^[abcd]d+))
```

---

If you are willing to change the requirements to only allow a limited subset of regular expressions then you can negate the regular expression by using boolean logic. For example if `^[abcd]d+` becomes `^[^abcd]|^[abcd][^d]`. It is then possible to find a valid input for this regular expression in reasonable time.

Comment: Hm, yeah, I was somewhat afraid of that, really.  But, ultimately, in this case, I can probably assure that the regexes we'll be supplied will be simple enough to negate by boolean logic, so that idea should help.  Thanks anyway!

Comment: @MarkByers:  It's always impressive to see a master regexer at work.  I love this -> _The following regular expression matches any string which is at least 10000 characters long and whose total length is a prime number:_

Answer (score 3):

I would do a loop, generating random combinations of random length, and test if matches the regexp. Repeat the loop until a not-match situation is reached.

Obviously, this would be inefficient. Are you sure you cannot invert the regexp and generate a match on the inverted regexp?

Comment: Actually, depending on the specificity of the regular expression, you may be quite likely to find a non-match in a very short time. For example, if you're trying to generate random text that is NOT an email, you probably have a good shot of getting it right on the first go. Nice solution!

Answer (score 2):

No this is impossible. There are an infinite number of regexes that match every string in the known universe. For example:

`/^/`
`/.*/`
`/[^"\\]*(\\.[^"\\]*)*$/`

etc.

This is because all these regexes can match *nothing at all* (which is something all strings have!)

Answer (score 0):

Can we reduce the infinite number of possibilities, by restricting to generate strings from a give character set.

For example, I can define the character set, `[QWERTYUIOP!@#$%^%^&*))_]` and all the strings I generate randomly should be born from this set. That way we can reduce the infinite nature of this problem?

In fact even I am looking for a utility like this, preferably in Python.