# Build a combination of strings that matches the given regex

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

Is there a way to build a combination of strings that matches a given regex. I was trying to think of this from a while and looking in for inputs / suggestions on this.

for example if I give a regex like this

```
reg : r'[ac][co]{1,2}o[unt]{1,3}'


output : ['account', 'ccoount', 'accoun', 'accout', 'accont']
```

Comment: Well, your expression actually "codes" [468 alternatives](https://regex101.com/r/nYPTRw/1). Why do you want to get those 5 only?

Comment: Is this your homework ? Maybe it's a business logic code.

Comment: What about `.*`? The output is infinite

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thats just the example output that I provided. Cant fit in all the words.

Comment: @VictorLee business logic.

Comment: Ok, that is a wording issue, but anyway, your answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20061268/python-regex-string-expansion).