# How to convert "[A-Z]" to "ABCD,,," by using RE in python

Tags: python, regex, string

Is it possible in python to **convert** a string e.g.

```
"[A-Z]" to "ABCDE...XYZ"
```

or

```
"[0-9]" to "012..9"
```

or other similar REs

by using the `re` python module.

Comment: Why would you use regular expressions for this rather than writing a basic parser?

Comment: Because i would like to do this in only one line like new = re.MyExtractor(old)

Comment: Why not make a function called `MyExtractor()` ? trying to do what you are doing with `re` isn't a really good solution

Comment: There's no need to do this in one line. Rethink your design.

Comment: Of course, if you only want alpha-numeric ASCII characters, then you can just check which characters match the given pattern.

Comment: AFAIK, `re` is used to pattern match and maybe replace with other patterns. So sure you could define something like replace `A-Z` with `ABC...Z` but then why not just do a parser like what other has suggested. In the end there is no one magical liner you can do  that isn't bloated with functions.

Comment: In regex, `[A-Z]` means any character between `A` and `Z` (any uppercase roman letter,) it does not mean each character between `A` and `Z` in sequence. You definitely do not want to use `re` for this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/496603/541038

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regular expressions are about matching, not generation.

You can, of course, pre-generate a sequence of all characters you care about and then match your RE against it, selecting only the matching ones.

```
import re

all_chars = "".join(chr(x) for x in range(32, 128))  # only ASCII here

digits_and_caps_rx = re.compile('([0-9]|[A-Z])')

print "".join(digits_and_caps_rx.findall(all_chars))
```

Comment: Interesting and nice solution